# scipy optimization with multiple constraints

Tags: optimization, data-science, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

How to find solution to a linear regression with multiple constraints on the coefficients in python?

[image]

Comment: A QP algorithm would be a good idea for this. SciPy does not have this but SLSQP is a more general-purpose NLP solver that can handle this. Note: Technically no method can solve your problem due to the strict inequalities. It is better to use <= instead of <.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen could you suggest a python code given a non-strict inequality?

Comment: [QuadProg](https://pypi.org/project/quadprog/) is a simple QP solver. For large problems [OSQP](https://osqp.org/) is interesting.  CVXPY is useful for modeling.

Answer (score 0):

cvxpy is a good choice:

```py
import cvxpy as cp 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1) 
y = 100*np.random.random(1) 
x = 200*np.random.random(1000)-100

b = cp.Variable(1000)

constraints = [-100<=b, b<=100, cp.sum(b)==2]
obj = cp.Minimize( cp.square(y-x@b) )
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints) 
val = prob.solve()
print(f"Objective value {val}")
print("b values: {0}".format(b.value))
```